# select rows with condition in multi rows of other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, phpmyadmin

I want to show all posts that user had followed. I have two tables are `post_tb` and `follow_tb`, linked column is `post_tb.user_id` and `follow_tb.follower_id`.
if i show all posts on the table i got sql condition like this

```
"select * from post_tb order by date_time desc;"
```

And this is sql condition that show only posts people they followed.

```
"select * from post_tb where user_id in(select follow_to_id from follow_tb where follow_tb.follower_id='$sessionid') order by date_time des;"
```

Both of them is work, but the second sql is every slow when number of records increase. Is there the better way?
thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Sub queries are slow instead use join

```
select * from post_tb  p
join follow_tb f ON(p.user_id = f.follow_to_id )
where f.follower_id='$sessionid'
order by date_time desc;
```